# Error: Test object id not in the object map: dmTablePopupMenu2 in a RFT script

Tags: rft

Exception occurred during playback of script `[Firewall.ASDMDcerpcInspectMap] [CRFCN0019E: RationalTestScriptException` on line 150 of script `Firewall.ASDMDcerpcInspectMap - com.rational.test.ft.ObjectNotInMapException: CRFCN0763E: Test object id not in the object map: dmTablePopupMenu2.].`
I am using IBM Rational Functional Tester Version: 8.3.0.1 and I found the above exception in few of my scripts. I cannot see any error on the script for objects present in the script but missing in the object map , Can Anybody tell me why am I facing this problem ans how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

This error gets thrown when  the actual object does not exist (or most likely deleted) from the Object Map however the script still has a reference for that object.

As per the error message above , could you locate what is the code on line 150 of the Script  ASDMDcerpcInpectMap  , and then try to track that object in the object map ?
So if the line 150 says  ..  **`button123().click();`** ..  then in the script explorer you should have an object by the name button123 when upon doubleclick should bring up the object map with button123() selected.
I supect the button123 is mising from the object map( deleted most likely).
Try to re-add that object to the object map ( by using the   TestObject-> Insert Test Object from the Object Map) and then right click on that object in the object map  and select   "Add to script"  , that should take care of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Prakash, I shall try this.

Comment: Prakash Could you please tell me under which panel in Eclipse(RFT)   is TestObject-> Insert Test object to object map,present?

Comment: If you open the Object Map(available in the script explorer view) , then Under Test Object menu you have Insert Test Object.